# How do I compare two times saved in a string in C#?

Tags: c#, database

They are currently saved in the format: 00H:00M:00S and I need to compare them before saving into my database. Is there any quick way to do it instead of just simply getting strings chars?

I need to compare them to save the users best time on solving the game.

Currently is better for me to use strings and not date cause i also need to display them in many places in the game, so it's easier to be in string.

I'm using this counter:

```
//set timer UI

    secondsCount += Time.deltaTime;
    if (timerText != null) {
        timerText.text = hourCount + "h:" + minuteCount + "m:" + (int)secondsCount + "s";

    }

    if(secondsCount >= 60){
        minuteCount++;
        secondsCount = 0;
    }else if(minuteCount >= 60){
        hourCount++;
        minuteCount = 0;
    }    
}
```

and at the end, need to know it this new amount of time is less then the one in the database.

thanks!

Comment: You could parse them to `TimeSpan`. Probably better if you stored them in your DB in an appropriate type as well and not as strings.

Comment: ultimately, if the data is a string and isn't naturally sortable (including same length and a left-to-right descending magnitude): you're going to have to parse it back to something like `TimeSpan`. You *might* get away with just `TimeSpan.Parse`, depending on the data. You might prefer to parse it to an integer (`int` or `long`) token that is the total number of seconds etc - that's easy to compare

Comment: The reason that you have to diplay it in many places is not a valid reason to store them as string instead of as `TimeSpan` or `DateTIme`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the following to convert from the string to a `DateTime`, and then compare the `DateTime`'s.

```
DateTime time = DateTime.ParseExact("01H:00M:00S", "HH\\H:mm\\M:ssS", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

then you can do:

```
bool b = time1 > time2;
```

For more information see: [DateTime.ParseExact](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.datetime.parseexact?view=netframework-4.7.2) and 
[Custom Date and Time Format Strings](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/custom-date-and-time-format-strings?view=netframework-4.7.2#using-the-escape-character). In the latter you will see that we need to escape the **H** and **M** with a backslash, else they would be interpreted as part of the format.

I answered the question as it is, though I'm not saying it's good to store times as strings.

Comment: i tried to do as you said but its getting me an error
FormatException: Invalid format string
System.DateTime.ParseExact (System.String s, System.String[] formats, IFormatProvider provider, DateTimeStyles style) (at /Users/builduser/buildslave/mono/build/mcs/class/corlib/System/DateTime.cs:1892)
System.DateTime.ParseExact (System.String s, System.String format, IFormatProvider provider, DateTimeStyles style) (at /Users/builduser/buildslave/mono/build/mcs/class/corlib/System/DateTime.cs:1870)

Comment: here's my code 

`DateTime t1 = DateTime.ParseExact (t, "HH\\H:mm\\M:ssS", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
  DateTime t2 = DateTime.ParseExact(tempo, "HH\\H:mm\\M:ssS", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);


  print (t2);
  if (t2<t1 | t =="00h:00m:00s"){
   www = new WWW (url + "atualizaTempos.php?login=" + PHPBehavior.login + "&tipoChave=" + i + "&tempo=" + tempo);
   StartCoroutine (atualizaTempos (www));
  }`

Comment: @Koda My code assumed you're using `H`, `M`, and `S` as in the first line of your question. You are using `h`, `m`, and `s` I presume. So you would need to change `"HH\\H:mm\\M:ssS"` to `"HH\\h:mm\\m:ss\\s"`.

Comment: i tried that, but i'm still gettint the same error... im sorry to bother, thanks for the patience!

Comment: @Koda can you paste the actual value of t and tempo here? Set a breakpoint on that first line, hover over them, copy, and paste here.

Comment: @Koda And did you copy my new string? I added an escape for the `s` as well in the new one. I tested it and it works.

Comment: it worked! some of my php code has dissapeared somehow, it wasn't antything from your code. again, sorry to bother! thank you